# How to highlight certain words over terminal always from all commands

Tags: linux, bash, unix, colors

I need to highlight certain keywords like "fail, failed, error, fatal, missing" over my terminal.

I need this with the output of ALL the commands, not any specific command. I assume I need to tweak my `bashrc` file for this.

To color I can use:

```
<input coming to terminal>|grep -P --color=auto 'fail|failed|error|fatal|missing|$'
```

I tried the following command but not helped:

```
tail -f $(tty) |grep -P --color=auto 'fail|failed|error|fatal|missing|$' &
[1]+  Stopped(SIGTTIN)        tail -f $(tty) | grep -P --color=auto 'fail|failed|error|fatal|missing|$'
```

Searched SO for answers but could not find any question which provides desired an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's really an elegant way to do this using the shell. Ideally, you'd get a terminal emulator with this kind a keyword highlighting built in. You can get some of the way by piping the output of `bash` through a filter that adds ANSI colour escapes. Here is a `sed` script, that replaces "fail" with (red)fail(normal):

```
s/fail/\x1B[31m&\x1B[0m/
t done

:done
```

Run `bash` with its output piped through `sed` like this:

```
$bash | sed -f color.sed
```

This mechanism is not without problems, but it works in some cases. Usually it's better just to collect up the output you want, and then pipe it through `sed`, rather than working directly with the `bash` output.

Comment: This really is a job for the terminal emulator.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I wrote "Ideally, you'd get a terminal emulator..." :)

Comment: Yup, just wanted to emphasize that as the real right answer :)

Comment: So given that this question has the linux and unix tags... can anyone name a terminal emulator that does this on those platforms? See my related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515553/is-there-a-linux-terminal-emulator-with-equivalent-functionality-to-iterm2-trigg

Comment: I don't get why this should be the job of the terminal emulator. Why do you think this is the case? Just adding a pipe with a command and the words I want to highlight seem the easier approach to use.